# Magento urlkey field - how can I increase field length?

Tags: magento

I am trying to fix a bug in magento with duplicate url keys. The product names are unique but because the urlkey field is cutting off 30 characters before product name duplicates are occuring and the url rewrite table just grows with each reindex.
this link appeared to offer an elegant solution
http://www.atwix.com/magento/duplicated-product-url-keys-in-community-edition/
BUT I don't think it will work as there will be no space to add the sku to the urlkey.

So my question is, is it possible to increase the length of the urlkey field please?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

magento system has cached the database's table filed length,

so clear magento cache.

click `Flush Magento Cache` button

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/cache-storage-management